# Model.[some model].ToList() is returning null

Tags: asp.net5

I am passing a Repository to the view as my Model and in the View, with the Repository I am inserting an entry to the DB, I **can see the entry in the DB** but when I use getFans() the application crushes with the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: constructor
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(ConstructorInfo constructor, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
```

The error is happening in this line:
    return _context.Fans.ToList();

**I have this Repository class:**

```
public class FanBookRepository : IFanBookRepository
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public FanBookRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public ICollection<Fan> getFans()
    {
        return _context.Fans.ToList<Fan>();
    }

    public void addFan(Fan fan)
    {
        _context.Fans.Add(fan);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**I have this View named Index:**

```
@model Shauli_Blog.Models.FanBookRepository
@{
    Model.addFan(new Fan("Asaf", "Karavani", System.DateTime.Now, "Male", new DateTime(1996, 10, 7)));

}

@{
    var fans = Model.getFans();

    foreach (var fan in fans)
    {
        <h1>@fan.FirstName</h1>
    }
}
```

**And this Controller:**

```
public class FanBookController : Controller
{
    IFanBookRepository _repository;

    public FanBookController(IFanBookRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_repository);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the repository to the view is the wrong thing to do. Create a class, which will be the viewmodel for the view, that takes in a list of the fans.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IList<Fan> Fans { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();

    viewModel.Fans = _repository.getFans();

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The idea is that you separate the data which is used in the view, by using a viewmodel, away from the source of that data. That way if the list of fans comes from another source, say an array rather than from `_repoistory`, then it won't matter to the view, since that does not need to change. It's all about reducing the cohesion between the view and the data source.

Getting back to your issue with the exception raised from

`_context.Fans.ToList();`

Are you sure that `_context.Fans` is not NULL? Perhaps you should change the function to

`return _context.Fans != null ? _context.Fans.ToList() : Enumerable.Empty<Fan>().ToList();`

Comment: I agree Jason and would also suggest using the null propagation for checking the null list and reacting
`_context?.Fans.Any() == true ?? new List<Fan>()`

Comment: Yes if you can use null propagation, then go for it.

Comment: Just for clarity, null propagation is a C# 6.0 feature.

Comment: Yes I understand Jason, That was my first approch. But then I reilaized that I wanted both showing the list of fans and at the bottom a "fan sign up". That is why I wanted to pass the reposetory so the would be able to send data to the model.

Comment: And _contex.Fans is not null, he also have a field where count = 0 even tough I can see the entry in the DB

Comment: Not trying to go of topic, but I saw ASPNET5 and maybe assumed null propagation was there.  There are so many version numbers out there, but we're using ASPNET5 on vs2015 (target 4.6.1) and null propagation works.